# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$(jwt.expiration)"

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jwt, spring-security

Cuando quiero abrir el servidor desde [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) me salta el error como que si algunas declaraciones o dependencias están mal. Este es el error:

> Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'expiration'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$(jwt.expiration)"

```java
package com.portfolio.ggp.Security.jwt;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JwtEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint{
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Falló el metodo commence");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        
    }
}
```

```java
package com.portfolio.ggp.Security.jwt;

import com.portfolio.ggp.Security.Entity.UsuarioPrincipal;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.UnsupportedJwtException;
import java.util.Date;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JwtProvider {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtProvider.class);
    
    @Value("$(jwt.secret)")
    private String secret;
    @Value("$(jwt.expiration)")
    private int expiration;
    
    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication){
        UsuarioPrincipal usuarioPrincipal = (UsuarioPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(usuarioPrincipal.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date()).setExpiration(new Date(new Date().getTime()+expiration*1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES512, secret)
                .compact();
    }
    
    public String getNombreUSuarioFromToken(String token){
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }
    
    public boolean validateToken(String token){
        try{
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e){
            logger.error("Token mal formado");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e){
            logger.error("Token no soportado");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e){
            logger.error("Token expirado");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            logger.error("Token vacio");
        } catch (SignatureException e){
            logger.error("Firma no válida");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.portfolio.ggp.Security.jwt;

import com.portfolio.ggp.Security.Service.UserDetailsImp;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;


public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtProvider.class);
    
    @Autowired
    JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsImp userDetailsServiceImp;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try{
            String token = getToken(request);
            if(token != null && jwtProvider.validateToken(token)){
                String nombreUsuario = jwtProvider.getNombreUSuarioFromToken(token);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsServiceImp.loadUserByUsername(nombreUsuario);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            } 
        }catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Fallo el metodo doFilterInternal");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    
    private String getToken(HttpServletRequest request){
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer"))
            return header.replace("Bearer", "");
        return null;
    }
}
```

```java
#Application.properties

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8111/backendggp?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

#JWT
jwt.secret = secret
jwt.expiration = 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, me confundí poniendo paréntesis en vez de corchetes en la parte de

```
@Value("${jwt.secret}") y @Value("${jwt.expiration}")
```